# Using a baseclass method return value?

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods

I have a method in my baseclass that returns a bool and I want that bool to determine what happens to the same overridden method in my derived class.

Base:

```
    public bool Debt(double bal)
    {
        double deb = 0;
        bool worked;

        if (deb > bal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Debit amount exceeds the account balance – withdraw cancelled");
            worked = false;
        }
        else

        bal = bal - deb;
        worked = true;

        return worked;
    }
```

Derived

```
public override void Debt(double bal)
    {
        // if worked is true do something

    }
```

Note that bal comes from a constructor I made earlier

Comment: Make sure your base class method is virtual: `public virtual bool Deb(double bal)` or your derived class will just hide it. Just a side note.

Comment: Also the return value type must match, otherwise you'll get a compiler error, `'<namespace>.Derived.Debt(double)': return type must be 'bool' to match overridden member '<namespace>.Base.Debt(double)'`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call the base class method using the `base` keyword:

```
public override void Debt(double bal)
{
    if(base.Debt(bal))
        DoSomething();

}
```

As indicated in the comments above, you either need to make sure that there is a virtual method with the same signature (return type and parameters) in the base class or remove the override keyword from the deriving class.

Comment: Might be best to bracket the area after the `if` and do your stuff there, instead of calling another method to do it.  Why make your call stack deeper than it has to be?

Comment: @Jeff - I put the method call there purely to indicate that something should happen there. It might as well be inline statements.

Comment: I see what you're getting at except there's no way to tell if the result is true or false

Comment: @TheAce: It's inside an `if` statement.  The `if` evaluates the return value of the base class's method.  If you fall into the if check, it was true.  Otherwise, it was false.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(base.Debt(bal)){
    // do A
}else{
    // do B
}
```

`base` refers to the base class. So `base.X` refers to `X` in the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Call the `base` method:

```
public override void Debt(double bal)
{
    var worked = base.Debt(bal);
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As several others have mentioned you can use `base.Debt(bal)` to call into your base class method. I also noticed that your base class method was not declared as virtual. C# methods are NOT virtual by default so you will not be override it in a derived class unless you have specified it as virtual in the base class.

```
//Base Class
class Foo
{
    public virtual bool DoSomething()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// Derived Class
class Bar : Foo
{
    public override bool DoSomething()
    {
        if (base.DoSomething())
        {
           // base.DoSomething() returned true
        }
        else
        {
           // base.DoSomething() returned false
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) what msdn has to say about virtual methods